# flowMatch metaclustering throws unexpteced error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance-matrix

I am currently using the flowMatch package in order to match clusters from multiple bootstrap runs applied to the same dataset. However, in quite a proportion of the runs, a certain error warning comes up:

`Error in if (mdist < 0) mdist = 0 : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

This error only shows up if the clustering tool prior to metaclustering is louvain Clustering but not when I use FlowSOM. Still, also with Louvain Clustering I get these error not everytime but only sometimes.

Does somebody here have experience with flowmatch and/or louvain clustering and can help?

I will not post my actual code here because the underlying analysis is quite massive but I used the flowMatch according to the same scheme as described in the flowMatch Documentation (section 7: Computing template from a collection of samples)

`

### load data (20 samples in total)

> ### ------------------------------------------------
>
> data(hd)
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------
>
> ### Retrieve each sample, clsuter it and store the
>
> ### clustered samples in a list
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------
>
> set.seed(1234) # for reproducable clustering
> cat('Clustering samples: ')
> Clustering samples:
> clustSamples = list()
> for(i in 1:length(hd.flowSet))

- {
- cat(i, ' ')
- sample1 = exprs(hd.flowSet[[i]])
- clust1 = kmeans(sample1, centers=4, nstart=20)
- cluster.labels1 = clust1$cluster
- clustSample1 = ClusteredSample(labels=cluster.labels1, sample=sample1)
- clustSamples = c(clustSamples, clustSample1)
- }
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

> ### ------------------------------------------------
>
> ### Create a template from the list of clustered samples
>
> ### the function returns an object of class "Template"
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------
>
> template = create.template(clustSamples
> `

In this scheme, this line `+ cluster.labels1 = clust1$cluster` inserts the cluster annotation vector, i.e. the results from your clustering. As I said, with FlowSOM no problem at all but with Louvain clustering in some cases the described error warning shows up.

Comment: Providing a reproducible example higly increases the chances to get an answer, and facilitates the work of those who want to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mata this is a bit tricky since the underlying pipeline is pretty complex and involves too much code. However, i will try my best to give some example data

Comment: `example.data.list <- replicate(10, expr = {
  data.frame(marker1 = runif(1000, 0, 100),
             marker2 = runif(1000, -3, 90),
             marker3 = runif(1000, -7, 81),
             marker4 = runif(1000, -2, 110),
             marker5 = runif(1000, 10, 120),
             cluster = sample(1:8, 1000, replace = T)) }, 
  simplify = F)`

Comment: `example.clustSamples = list()

for(i in 1:length(example.data.list)) {
  cat(i, ' ')
  sample1 = example.data.list[[i]][,1:5]
  cluster.labels1 = example.data.list[[i]][,"cluster"]
  clustSample1 = ClusteredSample(labels=cluster.labels1, sample=sample1)
  clustSamples = c(clustSamples, clustSample1)
 }

example.template1 = create.template(clustSamples, dist.type ='Euclidean')
`

Comment: I am sorry for the incovenient style, I am just not familiar yet with the formatting on Stackoverflow. In short form: input are several dataframes with measurements (marker1-5) plus a column for the annotation that a clustering algorithm has found. this list is then inserted into the flowMatch functions to create an object of class `Clustered Sample`. From these Samples, `create.template` creates the annotation of the metaclustering, i.e. which cluster in one dataframe corresponds to the other clusters from the other runs.